# How to use javascript to create a program which works (opens, reads, makes & displays calculations) with txt files?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, string, file

// In my programming course I am supposed to work with a specific code to complete assignments. Up until now, I have been using JavaScript as my programming language. This new assignment, however, is asking me to work with files and I believe I'll need to use another language because js doesn't work with files. Since I'm new to programming, I am not familiar with any other language. My assignment asks me to create a program code which has to:

1. create a .txt file
2. make a program which uses user-based input to calculate minimum, maximum, and average values
3. verify the file exists
4. use string functions/methods to parse the file content and add each score to an array

I have made a program which calculates and displays the values based on the user's input but its in javascript. My question is, how do I add the js program I had already made which does all the calculations to this program which asks me to open files? Will I have to start the whole thing over and do it in node.js (which seems like its the closes to js) or can I add my old js program to a new node.js program?

I tried teaching myself node.js but its really confusing; if someone can show me how to insert my previous js program into a node.js code I think I'll be good for this assignment.

```
// This program creates a file, adds data to the file, displays the file,
// appends more data to the file, displays the file, and then deletes the file.
// It will not run if the file already exists.

function createFile(filename)
{
    var fs = require('fs')

    fs.writeFile(filename, "C\tF\n",  function(err) 
    {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
    });

    for(var c = 0; c <= 50; c++)
    {
        var f = c * 9 / 5 + 32;
        fs.appendFile(filename, c + "\t" + f + "\n", function (err) 
        {
            if (err) 
            {
                return console.error(err);
            }
        });
    }
}

function readFile(filename)
{
    var file = require('readline').createInterface(
    {
      input: require('fs').createReadStream(filename)
    });

    file.on('line', function (line) 
    {
        console.log(line);
    });
}

function appendFile(filename)
{
    var fs = require('fs')

    for(var c = 51; c <= 100; c++)
    {
        var f = c * 9 / 5 + 32;
        fs.appendFile(filename, c + "\t" + f + "\n", function (err) 
        {
            if (err) 
            {
                return console.error(err);
            }
        });
    }
}

function deleteFile(filename)
{
    var fs = require("fs");

    fs.unlink(filename, function(err) 
    {
        if (err) 
        {
            return console.error(err);
        }
    });
}

function fileExists(filename)
{
    var fs = require('fs');
    return fs.existsSync(filename);
}

function main()
{
    var filename = "~file.txt";

    if(fileExists(filename))
    {
        console.log("File already exists.")
    }
    else
    {
        createFile(filename);
        readFile(filename);
        appendFile(filename);
        deleteFile(filename);
    }
}

main();
```

Comment: what's the problem with above? One piece of advice, Try one thing at a time.

Comment: Have you installed nodeJS and tried running that file with that? If so, what errors do you get? Also note that you are doing some asynchronous operations, they might get out of order (i.e. you might try to read from a file before it was created)

Comment: Yes, I have installed nodeJS and ran this file with that. This code here is not my code it's just an example from my teacher.